# How to do 'like' queries in Opa?

Tags: opa

My case is very simple. I need to do a contains/like search over a field. Based on [this documentation](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/wiki/Hello,-database) you can do a regex to achieve this:

```
items/item[name =~ ".*{value}.*"; skip pagination.startOn; limit pagination.numberOf; order +modifiedOn]
```

But I'm getting a compilation error at the `=~`operator. Checking the output of the compilation error I saw that this are the options that I've

```
Hint: expected "!=" or "<" or "<=" or "==" or ">" or ">=" or "[" or "as" or "_" or "else" or "then" or "if" or "do" or "type" or "with" or "match" or "exists" or "in" or ' ' or ' ' or <spacing>
```

Which of those options will allow me to do the regex query?

I'm using this version of opa (I'm stuck with it for the moment)

```
OPA version 0.9.2
(c) 2007-2012 MLstate, All Rights Reserved.
Build: 1815-(fe5cc09)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression support is quite new addition to the Opa, and you have outdated compiler. Note, that Mongo [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator may impact performance significantly because of how it uses indexes. See [the discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717851/mongodb-perform-a-text-search-in-a-document-field-using-high-level-api) on text search in Opa.