# How to filter records based in a multiple aggregation (list) in Opa?

Tags: opa

I've several objects that can be tagged, so the model is

```
type Content = {
  ...
  tags : list(int)
  ...   
}
```

How can I avoid loading all the records from MongoDB to check if the content is tagged by all the tags from a given list (AND logic)? or at list one of the tags of the given list (OR logic)?

**I've tried flatting the list in a string to use regex, but I'm also stuck there as you can see** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855810/how-to-do-like-queries-in-opa)

I'm using this version of opa (I'm stuck with it for the moment)

```
OPA version 0.9.2
(c) 2007-2012 MLstate, All Rights Reserved.
Build: 1815-(fe5cc09)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find documents with any tag from the list `l` with:

```
/db/coll[tags[_] in l]
```

For the reference look [here](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/wiki/The-database).

For the "AND logic" its more complicated. MongoDB have [`$all` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/), but it seems to be not implemented in Opa (at least it is not documented) :(

You can run Mongo JSON query

```
{ tags: { $all: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } }
```

with [low level MongoDB support](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/wiki/Low-level-MongoDB-support). Alternatively, you can ask multiple times for the tag:

```
/db/coll[tags[_] == frst and tags[_] == scnd and tags[_] == next];
```

But Opa does not support dynamic construction of DB queries, so you have to know the length of the list a priori (when writing the code).

Answer (score 0):

Probably using the hole expression [_], something like that

/db/path/to/content[tags[_] == "value"]